# updating ini file in java using rest webservice

Tags: java, rest

I need to update ini file in java using rest service.I could read file in browser but have no idea how to update it.Can anybody please help for the required method that would update my ini file.

dbform.java

```
public class dbform {

    public List<db> getAlldb(){
        List<db> dbList = null;

        try {
             File file = new File("test.ini"); // read ini file
             if (!file.exists()) {

                db DB = new db("dbname: test","password: test");
                dbList = new ArrayList<db>();
                dbList.add(DB);
                savedbList(dbList);     
             }
             else{

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                dbList = (List<db>) ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
             }
          } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }     
          return dbList;

    }

    private void savedbList(List<db> dbList){
          try {
             File file = new File("test.ini");
             FileOutputStream fos;

             fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
             oos.writeObject(dbList);
             oos.close();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }

}
```

Comment: And what is wrong with your code?

Comment: code is perfect but I need code for additional method to update ini file.

Comment: But you have a savemethod?

Comment: updated ini file is not in readable format . what changes should I make to convert it into readable form?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ini4j. 
The [ini4j] is a simple Java API for handling configuration files in Windows .ini format. Additionally, the library includes Java Preferences API implementation based on the .ini file. 
http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Check your code there seems to be some issue in the way you have called the function. You don't seem to be passing the dbList into the replaceData() function. Probably it will be something like this

```
public void replaceData(List<db> dbList){ return DBform.savedbList(dbList); }
```

Comment: updated ini file is not in readable format . what changes should I make to convert it into readable form?

Comment: Since you are using ObjectOutputStream it writes to the file in binary serialized form. If you want to make it human readable form then either PrintWriter or BufferedWriter needs to be used.